# Ninject and dynamic WithConstructor/WithMeta and RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, ninject, rhino-mocks

In my project I have an IoC container that gets initialized the usual way with a ServiceModule. When I write unit tests, I want to be able to bind to either a StrictMock, DynamicMock, PartialMock or Stub. In the past I had a FakeServiceModule that would bind everything to StrictMocks, but this is very restrictive, and I wanted to expand this to allow creating a mock type of my choosing.

To achieve this I created the following.

```
public class NinjectMocking
{
    public Type TypeToMock { get; set; }
    public MockType MockTypeToUse { get; set; }
    public IBindingWithOrOnSyntax<Type> BindingWithOrOnSyntax { get; set; }   
}

public enum MockType
{
    Stub,
    Strict,
    Dynamic,
    Partial
}
```

The idea is that I would initialise the fake service module like so:

```
        foreach (var mockType in _mocks)
        {
            object ninjaMock;

            switch (mockType.MockTypeToUse)
            {
                case MockType.Strict:
                    {
                        ninjaMock = _mockRepository.StrictMock(mockType.TypeToMock);
                        break;
                    }
                case MockType.Dynamic:
                    {
                        ninjaMock = _mockRepository.DynamicMock(mockType.TypeToMock);
                        break;
                    }
                case MockType.Partial:
                    {
                        ninjaMock = _mockRepository.PartialMock(mockType.TypeToMock);
                        break;
                    }
                case MockType.Stub:
                    {
                        ninjaMock = _mockRepository.Stub(mockType.TypeToMock);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        ninjaMock = _mockRepository.StrictMock(mockType.TypeToMock);
                        break;
                    }
            }

            if (mockType.BindingWithOrOnSyntax == typeof(ConstructorArgument))
                Bind(mockType.TypeToMock).ToMethod(m => ninjaMock).w
                    .WithConstructorArgument(mockType.BindingWithOrOnSyntax);

            else
                Bind(mockType.TypeToMock).ToMethod(m => ninjaMock);
        }
```

Having been initliazed with a list of mocks...

```
       NinjectMocking ninjectMocking = new NinjectMocking();
        ninjectMocking.TypeToMock = typeToAdd;
        ninjectMocking.MockTypeToUse = MockType.Dynamic;
```

This all works perfectly. However, and here comes the question, some of our bindings need either .WithConstructorArgument or .WithMetaData as in

```
        Bind<ISomeRepository>().ToMethod(m => someRepository)
        .WithConstructorArgument("context", ctx => new TestDataContext());
```

and maybe some others in the future. That is why I have the BindingWithOrOnSyntax property in the NinjectMocking class. So my new initializer may look something like this:

```
        NinjectMocking ninjectMocking = new NinjectMocking();
        ninjectMocking.TypeToMock = typeToAdd;
        ninjectMocking.MockTypeToUse = MockType.Dynamic;
        ninjectMocking.BindingWithOrOnSyntax.WithConstructorArgument("context", constructorArgument);
```

The problem is I don't know how to make it use that in the binding. What I would like to do is something like

Bind(mockType.TypeToMock).ToMethod(m => ninjaMock).[WhatGoesHere]

I don't really know how to do it with the [WhatGoesHere] bit, or how else to define the Bind so that it uses whatever I pass in, in the BindingWithOrOnSyntax property. My last desperate attempt was to try force it via something like

```
            if (mockType.BindingWithOrOnSyntax == typeof(ConstructorArgument))
                Bind(mockType.TypeToMock).ToMethod(m => ninjaMock)
                    .WithConstructorArgument(mockType.BindingWithOrOnSyntax);
```

But that obviously doesn't work.

Any pointers in the right direction, or even if there is a better way to achieve this, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an IOC container during unit testing.  An IOC container is to be used at runtime to inject your dependencies into your components.  During unit testing, **you** create your components with mocked/stubbed dependencies.  If your components are resolving dependencies directly from the IOC container, you're not using the container properly.